# Is there a deep learning model when train data and test data (or real data) have some common and uncommon labels?

Tags: neural-networks, datasets, resource-request

I am building DL model that predict test data (or real) that has some different labels compared to training dataset.

My semi-supervised model is kind of terrible to predict test data (77~85% ish), and I want to improve the test score.

Is there is any DL paper about this kind of work? The most similar area I can think is Domain-adaptation area. If it's just domain adaptation genre, then what papers can you recommend to me?

And

I'm trying to make train dataset with multiple datasets that have common labels but also have uncommon labels. (these datasets from same domain by the way) these datasets have some common features but also have other features too. So the integration of these data is kind of unusual thing to me, is there good tips or guide for this kind of data integration?